# Dynamically append and remove substring from NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring, substring

I am dynamically appending and removing substring from NSString -

At specific action I am appending using (I am using comma separator while adding a new string)-

```
self.selectedString = [self.selectedString length] < 1 ? newSelectedString 
                                                       : [self.selectedString stringByAppendingFormat:@",%@",newSelectedString];
```

Removing - 
Now this comma is creating problem for me when removing string.
Currently I am using a solution for this as -

```
self.selectedString = [self.selectedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:newSelectedString
                                                                     withString:@""];

NSRange rangeSingleComma = [self.selectedString rangeOfString:@","];
NSRange rangeDoubleComma = [self.selectedString rangeOfString:@",,"];
if (rangeSingleComma.location == [self.selectedString length] - 1) {
    self.selectedString = [self.selectedString substringToIndex:[self.selectedString length] - 1];
}
if (rangeSingleComma.location == 0) {
    self.selectedString = [self.selectedString substringFromIndex:1];
}
if (rangeDoubleComma.location != NSNotFound) {
    self.selectedString = [self.selectedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@",,"
                                                                         withString:@","];
 }
```

But This is a very dirty approach, can any one suggest a good approach for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to store this comma separated list as a string? Instead, try maintaing an NSArray/NSMutableArray of NSString's. That makes it easy to add or remove any item at will. When you need the comma-separated string representation of the array, just do:

```
 [self.selectedArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]
```

If you'd like to still use your `self.selectedString` property, just put the above line of code in a getter method:

```
 - (NSString *) selectedString {
      return [self.selectedArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]
 }
```

Comment: Yea. it is definitely a better approach, i will use this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this

```
NSString *str = @"aaa,bbb,ccc";
NSMutableArray *arr = [[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];

int indexToRemove = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++) {
    NSString *string = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
    if([string isEqualToString:@"aaa"])
    {
        indexToRemove = i;
        break;
    }
}

if(indexToRemove != -1)
{
    [arr removeObjectAtIndex:indexToRemove];
}

NSString *newString = [arr componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Comment: +1 for good suggestion, but i like Adam's suggestion, so i will go with that approach.